# How to create new array using of existing array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array that has `from` and `to`.
I want to create a new array, each of which is a separate object.

For example: I have *timeDetail* and I want create *time*

```js
var timeDetail=[{from:12:00:00 ,to:13:00:00}{from:11:00:00 ,to:10:00:00}{from:01:00:00 ,to:02:00:00}]
    
var time=[{value:12:00:00}{value:13:00:00}{value:11:00:00}{value:10:00:00}{value:01:00:00}{value:02:00:00}]
```

I did that

```js
this.state.timeDetail.map((i)=>{
    var a=i.from;
    var b =i.to;
    var time=[];
    time.push({ Id: time.length+1, Value: a });
    time.push({ Id: time.length+1, Value: b });
    this.setState({
      time :time
    })  
})
```

But only the last value is replaced `time=[{Id:1,value:01:00:00}{Id :2,value:02:00:00}]`

Comment: `timeDetail.reduce(( time, detail ) => [ ...time, { value: detail.from }, { value: detail.to }], []);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are mulltiple ways to approach your problem, but `map` is only capable of returning an element of element. You have no way of returning 2 elements per 1 looped map parameter.

So you can either

- do a map of nested arrays `[[{value: x}, {value: y}], [...]]` and then flatten it
- [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) it to a single array
- or simply loop over the original array with [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and push the individual elements.

The simplest out of the 3 is the last mentioned `forEach` loop:

```js
someMethod = () => {
  const { timeDetail } = this.state
  const time = []
  timeDetail.forEach(({ from, to }) => {
     time.push({ value: from })
     time.push({ value: to })
  })
  this.setState({ timeDetail: time })
}
```

Next important thing to note - look how I moved the `setState()` outside of the `forEach` loop, which is something you should always strive to do.

That's also the reason why your state got update only once. **The `setState()` method is asynchronous and does not mutate the state directly, instead it creates a pending state transition**. To put it in simpler terms - never put `setState()` inside a loop, instead mutate the array first and then set the mutated array as the new state.

Outside of the buggy behaviour, even if it worked, your application would be much less performant because of updating state on every loop iteration.

- You can read up more on this in [the react docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate)

Comment: Thanks ..Nice answer - very well explained.